# Datastream streamed (backfilled) table to bigquery missing rows

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, google-datastream

So I'm using Datastream's new feature to stream data from Cloud SQL MySQL database to BigQuery, I've set the maximum data staleness of the stream to 8 hours.

**THE PROBLEM:**

To initialise the stream I performed a backfill on my tables. Datastream indicated that the **backfill is complete** and when I go to BigQuery in the table preview and using the query `SELECT * FROM mydataset.__TABLES__` the row count and size of the table correspond to the expected value.

**HOWEVER**

When I query the table like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mydataset.table
```

I get a much lower row count. The correct number of rows appears later after the maximum data staleness time is exceeded (after 8 hours in my case).

**MY QUESTION**:

Is this behaviour normal ? Isn't the backfilled data supposed to be available in bigquery if Datastream indicated that the backfill is complete?

NOTE: this Datastream MySQL-to-BigQuery feature is still in preview

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same problem with the same configuration (CloudSQL MySQL -> BigQuery), but with staleness set to 15 minutes. The same thing happened to me last time when I ran the Datastream. I presume that this is BigQuery "crunching" the data in the background somewhere?